# Auto config Firebase SDK in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

- I have a React app that I'd like to deploy to multiple environments (dev, staging, prod).
- each env is a separate Firebase project with its own config (apiKey, databseURL, etc). currently I hold multiple `firebase-config.json` for each env and use a switch in source code to determine which to use.
- I am using Firebase hosting for the app.
- The [hosting docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls?authuser=0#sdk_auto_configuration) state that I can fetch a special reserved url `/__/firebase/init.json` (or script in `/__/firebase/init.js`) that firebase hosting prepares for each project separately so I can init the correct instance of the firebase app for that environment. Also see the blog post [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/easier-configuration-for-firebase-on-web.html)

What I can't figure out is: fetching the special js/json file over the network is async and in the meantime the react app is initialising and requires the firebase app for auth and other operations. Is there a way I can complete the firebase init and have a firebase app instance ready before react has started-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this firebase-CLI command:

`firebase setup:web --json`

It will output the json required for initialising the firebase app based on the active firebase app (`firebase use`).
Just need to include the resulting json in the build chain.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you came around to use it? It isn't clear to me.

Comment: Running this command will provide a json object that includes all of the data required to init a firebase app instance in code: `apiKey, projectId, etc`. You can use it to dynamically create a config file for your firebase init based on the firebase project being used. This way, when you switch projects, you can still have a valid init config for firebase

Comment: @mr.bjerre it's used in the example project https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web-react/blob/master/example.  Specifically, it's in the `package.json` as a script, `createfirebaseconf`.

Comment: @ShaiBen-Tovim `firebase setup:web` says "This command is deprecated. Instead, use 'firebase apps:sdkconfig web' to get web setup information."  But I'm unable to run `firebase --non-interactive --token <MY_TOKEN> apps:sdkconfig --out firebase.json WEB <MY_APP_ID>` because I get "FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument." in the firebase-debug.log.  Does it work for you?

Comment: This no longer works. Is there an updated way to do with with `apps:sdkconfig`?

Comment: Is there a way to make the new the new command output just the JSON instead of the comments and firebase.initializeApp? Something like `firebase apps:sdkconfig web --json`

Answer (score 3):

`firebase setup:web --json` has been deprecated.

You can now use `firebase apps:sdkconfig web --json` instead.

Full info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984776/firebase-next-js-serverless-on-gcp-how-to-manage-staging-production-loca/59592541#59592541).

Comment: Amazing, this should be on top